# ASP.NET Core Web API no such host is know

Tags: xamarin, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Web have ASP.NET Core Web API and Xamarin Forms applications. API has a wildcard SSL and Xamarin mobile app consumes API methods via HttpClient lib. Some clients' apps throws exception detailed below and cannot figure out why? By the way web API running in two servers behind a load balancer service.

Exception Message : System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No such host is known ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1034614d0 + 0x005a3> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1034614d0 + 0x00798> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x103469170 + 0x006b7> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) <0x10346ace0 + 0x00454> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x103468100 + 0x0051b> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x10346f430 + 0x002e7> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at ACOMobile.Handler.TimeOutHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage req, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) <0x103999330 + 0x00323> in <b805f9b6a25e429698b7d1bd95b3e35a#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) <0x1034330b0 + 0x005f4> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at ACOMobile.Base.BaseClient.Post (ACOMobile.Base.BasePostModel postModel) <0x10399b340 + 0x00bcf> in <b805f9b6a25e429698b7d1bd95b3e35a#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  InnerException : System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): No such host is known
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1034614d0 + 0x005a3> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  StackTrace :   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x1034614d0 + 0x00798> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x103469170 + 0x006b7> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) <0x10346ace0 + 0x00454> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x103468100 + 0x0051b> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) <0x10346f430 + 0x002e7> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at ACOMobile.Handler.TimeOutHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage req, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct) <0x103999330 + 0x00323> in <b805f9b6a25e429698b7d1bd95b3e35a#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) <0x1034330b0 + 0x005f4> in <f4ed0f0e3fd9469cb377e6d7103f8b99#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0
at ACOMobile.Base.BaseClient.Post (ACOMobile.Base.BasePostModel postModel) <0x10399b340 + 0x00bcf> in <b805f9b6a25e429698b7d1bd95b3e35a#d91a1c6850e8c834ef38537a04c36310>:0  Message : No such host is known Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal HResult : -2147467259 Source : mscorlib Explanation : Unable to post data to API! Project Platform => PRODUCTION

Comment: if this only happens to some users, it sounds like they are having a DNS failure.  Are they in poor or low connectivity?

Comment: I'm not sure the connection is poor or not. But DNS failure is a good idea. Thank  you @Jason